# Why silicon doesn't have the electronic configuration [Ne] 3s¹ 3p³?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electronic-configuration, atomic-structure

I have read that half or fully filled orbitals provide more stability to the element due to symmetry and exchange energy.It is the reason for electronic configuration of Cr-[Ar]4s¹3d⁵.
Then, why doesn't silicon have the electronic configuration [Ne] 3s¹ 3p³? Doesn't that provide extra stability?

If this is not the case when do half and fully filled orbitals provide extra stability?

Comment: Because having the $s$ level happy is the biggest win here.

Comment: It depends what requires higher energy - the pairing electrons in the current orbital group, or filling the next orbital group instead. The energy difference 3s-3p is higher than for 4s-3d, with the latter even swapping the levels.

Answer (score 2):

The ground state electronic configuration of silicon is $\ce{[Ne] 3s^2 3p^2}$. It seems that the atom would have gained more stability if it were $\ce{[Ne] 3s^1 3p^3}$ because half filled orbitals are very stable. But here is a s orbital which is actually fully filled in the former configuration. Since fully filled orbitals are also stable, this provides some stability.
But here comes another factor; since two electrons of opposite spin are paired, energy increased and stability decreases. But we also see that s orbital is closer to nucleus which means the positive energy of inter electronic repulsion is actually compensated by negative potential energy of attraction from the nucleus.
So these four factors are underlying below the configuration of silicon being $\ce{[Ne] 3s^2 3p^2}$.

Answer (score -2):

The energy difference between the s and p orbitals in multielectron atoms is much much bigger than the difference between s and d orbitals when talking about transition elements.